# DNS Server Spoofed Request Amplification DDoS Mitigation for Server 2008 R2

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008-r2, ddos, pci-compliance

We are undergoing PCI Compliance checks and our external nameservers (all Windows Server 2008 R2) have been hit by Nessus Plugin ID: 35450 (verbage below). Although this is a low severity hit, I see DDoS in the title and I freak.

Plugin ID: 35450
Name: DNS Server Spoofed Request Amplification DDoS
Synopsis: The remote DNS server could be used in a distributed denial of service attack.
Plugin Output: The DNS query was 17 bytes long, the answer is 449 bytes long.

I googled the heck out of this to no avail. Please respond if you have any suggestions.

I did find ways to test (below) but no luck on any mitigation steps...

On Linux:
dig . NS @
[example: dig . NS @192.168.1.1]

Or on the web:
http://isc1.sans.org/dnstest.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your DNS server to issue "REFUSED" in response to queries for the root hints (i.e. `dig . NS`) instead of returning the current list of root name servers.

Not being familiar with that particular DNS software I can't advise on how to do that.

Note that this Nessus test does not imply a weakness in your *own* network security - you cannot suffer a network breach because of this.

Instead it means that people may send spoofed queries to your server whose replies can than be used as part of a DDoS against *someone else*.  See [RFC 5358](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5358).